# Weak convergence of the functional generated by $f^k_n(x)=n^ke^{-nx}$ (Physicist trying to solve easy functional analysis exercise)

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

I need to study the boundedness and the weak convergence of the functionals on $L_1([0,+\infty])$ generated by  the functions:
$$f^0_n(x)=e^{-nx}$$  $$f^1_n(x)=ne^{-nx}$$ $$f^2_n(x)=n^2e^{-nx}$$
It was easy to show that:
$$F^0_n(\phi)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-nx}\phi(x)dx$$ $$F^1_n(\phi)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}ne^{-nx} \phi(x)dx$$ $$F^2_n(\phi)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}n^2e^{-nx}\phi(x)dx$$ are bounded for every fixed $n$:
$$|F^0_n(\phi)|=|\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-nx}\phi(x)dx|≤||e^{-nx}|| ⋅||\phi||=(1/n ) ⋅||\phi||$$ and similarly:
$$F^1_n(\phi)|≤1⋅||\phi||$$ $$F^2_n(\phi)≤n⋅||\phi||.$$

Let's study the weak convergence of $F^0_n(\phi)$. We need to compute the limit: $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-nx}\phi(x)dx.$$ At this purpose I think the only choice is to use the Dominated convergence theorem. Since: $$e^{-nx}\phi(x)≤g(x)\phi(x),$$ with: $$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
2,  & \text{if 0 ≤ $x \le 1/2$} \\[2ex]
1/x, & \text{if $x \ge 1/2$}
\end{cases}$$ and:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}e^{-nx}\phi(x)=\begin{cases}
\phi(0),  & \text{if x=0} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $x>0$}
\end{cases}=0 \space a.e.$$ we have:$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-nx}\phi(x)dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\lim_{n\to +\infty}e^{-nx}\phi(x)dx.$$ **Now I do not know how to evaluate the last integral. Should it be zero since the integrand is $0\space a.e.$ or should it be $\phi(0)$?**(Probably I have a weak understanding of $L_1$ integration).

Anyways, going on with the exercise, when I proceed to evaluate: $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}ne^{-nx}\phi(x)dx.$$ **I do not know what $n$-independent function choose to dominate $ne^{-nx}\phi(x)$ if there exist any.** Skipping this step we now have: $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}ne^{-nx}\phi(x)=\begin{cases}
+\infty,  & \text{if x=0} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $x>0$}
\end{cases}$$ In this case the limit seems to be the "function" called by physicists delta, and I am tempted to write:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}ne^{-nx}\phi(x)dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\lim_{n\to +\infty}ne^{-nx}\phi(x)dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\delta(x)\phi(x)dx=\phi(0).$$ **But these last steps seem to me highly unrigorous, even if the result seems correct. Any help appreciated**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionals on $L^1[0,\infty)$ are given by $$F_g(f)=\int\limits_0^\infty g(x)f(x)\,dx$$ where $g\in L^\infty[0,\infty)$ and $\|F_g\|=\|g\|_\infty.$ In your case the first sequence of functionals is bounded in $L^\infty[0,\infty)$ by $1.$ The other two series are not bounded, as the norms are equal $n$ and $n^2,$ respectively. Therefore the second and the third series cannot be weakly convergent. The first series tends weakly to $0.$ Indeed for $f\in L^1$ we get $$\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-nx}|f(x)|\,dx =\int\limits_0^{n^{-1/2}}e^{-nx}|f(x)|\,dx\\ +\int\limits_{n^{-1/2}}^\infty e^{-nx}|f(x)|\,dx\\ \le \int\limits_0^{n^{-1/2} }|f(x)|\,dx +e^{-n^{1/2}}\|f\|_1$$ The  two terms above tend to $0.$